# Finding common values in step_1 and step_2 when values in step_1 is null we need to fetch the values in step_2 in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

**Requirement:**  Identify the common values(customer_id)  from Step 1 and Step 2 (if the customer_id from step 1 is null then need to consider all the customer_id from step 2)

We need to fetch the common values in step_1 and step_2 when values in step_1 is null we need to fetch the values in step_2 in BigQuery

**Case_1: If step_a values are null we need to fetch step_b**

```
 with step_a as (select null as customer_id union all
    select null as customer_id union all
    select null as customer_id union all
    select null as customer_id),
    
    
    step_b as (select 1 as customer_id union all
    select 2 as customer_id union all
    select 3 as customer_id union all
    select 4 as customer_id )
    
    (Select customer_id from step_a)
          intersect distinct
     (select customer_id from step_b)    


  Excepted Result
    customer_id 
    1
    2
    3
    4

**Actual Result:** No Result
```

**Case_2: If step_a values are not null we need to fetch common values from step_a and step_b**

```
with step_a as (select 1 as customer_id union all
        select 2 as customer_id union all
        select 3 as customer_id union all
        select 4 as customer_id),
   
        step_b as (select 1 as customer_id union all
        select 2 as customer_id union all
        select 3 as customer_id union all
        select 4 as customer_id )
        
(Select customer_id from step_a)
  intersect distinct
(select customer_id from step_b)
```

**With above query we are getting result as per expectation**

```
 customer_id 
    1
    2
    3
    4


We are having four scenarios
case4     a= 5, b=null           output=none
case3     a= 1,2 b= 1,2,5        output=1,2
case2     a= 1,2 b= 5            output=none
case1     a=null, b=1,2          output= 1,2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [**`intersect`**](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#intersect) which will fetch only those rows which are available in both the queries. In your first case that is not happening at all thus you are not getting any result.

Edit:

```sql
declare row_count_a default 0;
declare row_count_b default 0;

create temp table step_a as (select null as customer_id union all
    select 1 as customer_id union all
    select 2 as customer_id union all
    select null as customer_id);

create temp table step_b as (select null as customer_id union all
select 1 as customer_id );


set row_count_a = (select count(*) from step_a where customer_id is not null);
set row_count_b = (select count(*) from step_b where customer_id is not null);

if row_count_a = 0 then 
  select distinct * from step_b where customer_id is not null;  # case 1 a=null,null b=1,2 output=1,2
else if row_count_b > 0 then  # case 3 a=1,2 b=5 output=none , a=1,2,3 b=1,2 output=1,2     
      select distinct * from (
        (select customer_id from step_a where customer_id is not null)
          intersect distinct
        (select customer_id from step_b where customer_id is not null));
    end if;
end if;
```

Comment: Thanks @Sayan Bhattacharya. We need to fetch common values from both query. if in step_a all values are null i need to fetch only step_b. for example_1 Step_a = 1,2,3 and step_b 1,2 we need 1,2. for example_2 Step_a = null,null  and step_b 1,2, we need 1,2

Comment: for example_1 Step_a = 1,2,3 and step_b 1,2 Result from above query 1,2,3 we need 1,2

example_2 Step_a = null,null and step_b  =1,2, we need 1,2 
We have two scenario

Comment: @hepzi What if Step_a = 1,null and step_b =1,2 then ? I mean is in step_a all the values will have null ?

Comment: for Step_a = 1,null and step_b =1,2 we need 1 as result. In case step_a = null,null step_b= 1,2 we need 1,2

Comment: Great work. Thanks for marvelous support. Keep doing great work @Sayan Bhattacharya

Comment: Hi @Sayan Bhattacharya
 if step_a= 1,2 and step_b = 5 We should not get any values. But above query return step_a results

Comment: yes @Sayan Bhattacharya

Comment: we should not get any values  @Sayan Bhattacharya

Answer (score 0):

You are probably in need of a `full outer join`:

```sql
with step_a as (
    select null as customer_id union all
    select null as customer_id union all
    select null as customer_id union all
    select null as customer_id
),
    
step_b as (
    select 1 as customer_id union all
    select 2 as customer_id union all
    select 3 as customer_id union all
    select 4 as customer_id
 )
 
 select distinct * 
 from step_a
 full outer join step_b;
```

**Output:**

| a.customer_id | b.customer_id |
| --- | --- |
| null | 1 |
| null | 2 |
| null | 3 |
| null | 4 |

Comment: Thanks for your response @aleix CC. In case in step_a we are having not null values and step_b not null values we need common values from both steps.

Comment: What do you mean? Can you add an example of how the output of the query would look like in this case?